# Loading Indicator When Switching Views In Angular

Tags: angularjs

Work on asp.net mvc 5, It's no doubt Angular is an awesome framework for building modern web applications. Need to load more than a little data. Need help on loading data indicator in button event .Is it possible to create a directive for loading indicator. Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume that default status.isUploadingStarted is false;

When user click on upload button, at that time we will make the

```
$scope.status.isUploadingStarted = true;
```

So,In the case,span will active and it will show spinner,After loading the data,make it false;

```
<button ng-click="upload()" class="btn upload-custom btn-primary" ng-disabled="status.isUploadingStarted">
                {{status.isUploadingStarted? "Uploading" : "Upload File"}}
                <span ng-show="isUploadingStarted"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
            </button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.status = {};
$scope.status.isUploadingStarted = false;

$scope.upload = function(){
   $scope.status.isUploadingStarted = true;  //data is loading
   //data loaded successfully
   $scope.status.isUploadingStarted = false;
}
```

You can use in this way.In controller simply change the value of **isUploadingStarted**

Let me know if you have any classifications

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply. will you please describe detail.

Comment: in your approach ui is not freeze,want  a process when loading indicator appear rest of ui must be block. after complete the desired task spinner must be closed.

Comment: us-spinner directive you can use

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
    <div ng-app='demo'>
<div ng-controller='loadData'>
  <button ng-click='uploadData($event)' >upload</button><indicator-tag></indicator-tag>
<div>{{dataUploaded}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
    var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('loadData', function($scope,$rootScope,$http){
  var buses=[
  {
    "name":"aaa",
    "status":"A/C"
  },
  {
    "name":"bbb",
    "status":"Non A/C"
  },
  {
    "name":"ccc",
    "status":"A/C"
  },
  {
    "name":"ddd",
    "status":"Non A/C"
  }
  ];
   $scope.uploadData = function() {
   var initial="Loading...";
   var afterLoading="uploaded";
   $rootScope.$broadcast('changeIndicator',initial);
   $http.get("/echo/json/", buses).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.dataUploaded=buses;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('changeIndicator',afterLoading);
    });
   };
});
demo.directive('indicatorTag', function() {
      return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    template: '<span>{{text}}</span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       scope.changeText = function(data){
         scope.text = data;
       };
         scope.$on('changeIndicator',function(event, data){
             scope.changeText(data)
         });
     }
  };
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/peqmyd3v/1/)